# Having trouble to convert a string date to a date object

Tags: php

This is the current date I got in PHP from getLastLogin():

```
Apr 22 2016, 01:44:17 CEST
```

This is the code that I use to convert it:

```
$ymd = null;
$dateObject = DateTime::createFromFormat('M d Y, H:i:s T', $player->getLastLogin());
if($dateObject){ $ymd = $dateObject->format("m/d/Y"); }
echo $ymd;
```

There is no error but it never goes into the if statement and therefore it's still null when I try to echo it.

My function `getLastLogin()` is working as well, so I think it's narrowed down to the actual format.

Thanks for help!

Comment: `$dateObject` seems to have failed... What does `$player->getLastLogin()` hold>

Comment: Cannot replicate: https://eval.in/558166

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ is right, the ONLY problem in your code is that `$player->getLastLogin()` doesn't have a value like "Apr 22 2016, 01:44:17 CEST". Display `$player->getLastLogin()` to take a look at its value.

Comment: `$ymd; ` in start script You use undefined variable you need initialize this variable by `$ymd = null;`

Comment: @Naumov won't make a difference unless `$dateObject` assignment fails.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ `Notice: Undefined variable: ymd` I'm talk about this error.

Comment: I've fixed the initialisation of the variable by doing: $ymd = null;
The getLastLogin() is outputting the date I posted in the very top of this post.